# Special characters are destroyed

Tags: php, xhtml, character-encoding

http://asexpress.de/

The problem is that all the special characters a destroyed. 
The Default Characterset of  MySQL Database is utf-8 and on my website i am also using the charset utf-8

On my localserver on windows i have no problem. And this website in hosted on Linux Server.

Any tip?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox tells me the delivered charset is Latin1.

If there are serverside settings for the charset, they override the `<meta>`, so check the server-settings.

Or try sending the charset-header using PHP, if it's not permitted to change the server-configuration.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```